# Kafka Streams Initializer is being called more than once for the same key

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

## Intro

Imagine a fitness tracker app: we need to accumulate the total distance walked by the user and for that, I decided to use Kafka Streams *[SessionWindows](http://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#session-windows)*. 
By the end of the day, I want to generate a daily report and save it in to DB. That report shouldn't be altered after its generation, so, I don't want to include late-arriving events. 
My plan was to set the [windowed aggregation's](http://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#aggregating) `inactivity gap` to *one day long* and discard any events that will arrive later the next day in the `initializer` method. 
Let me illustrate that with a silly example: 
`key              value (walked meters) event time`    
`user-1-device-1  10                    today    1:10 PM`
`user-1-device-1  20                    today    1:11 PM`
`user-1-device-1  20                    today    1:12 PM`
`...`
`user-1-device-1  25                    today    2:00 PM`
The daily report is generated by the end of the day
`user-1-device-1  10                    tomorrow 1 PM` <- this event with the *same key* should be ignored for the report

## Problem

I was hoping to detect late-arriving events and prevent overriding the daily report with the new values by checking whether the report is already created in an `initializer` method. But apparently, that method is being called **more than once** for the **same key**, actually, it's called every time the new record is arriving, which seems to be not working as designed according to the [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#aggregating):

> When a record key is received **for the first time for a given window**, the initializer is called (and called before the adder).

## Question

Could anyone explain, how exactly the Kafka Streams aggregation works in the case of Session Window, so that the `initializer` is called more than once for the same key? I suspect there's something related to the expression "for the first time for a given window", but I don't understand what a "given window" is in terms of the Session Window.